# how to enable/disable mac build-in keyboard programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard

I use command:

> sudo kextunload                                                                                               /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext
>
> sudo kextload                                                                                                 /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext

to disable/enable mac build-in keyboard manually. It seems to unload/load driver for build-in keyboard and works fine.

**So how to do it in the code.** In my opinion, I needed to do two tasks.
1. unload/load the driver
2. run sudo command

The first task is simple, just use **KextManager** API will do me favor.

The second one, I found Apple documents say when you want to run **sudo** authentication task, with the security consideration, you should use something like:
1. launchd
2. SMJobless
3. XPC service
4. etc...
to abstract the high rights task to a sub helper tool run as a launchd process, and use XPC service to communication between main application and this helper tool.

I tried all of these, and helper tool works fine, but when I use

> KextManagerUnloadKextWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard"));

in the helper tool. It did not work, the build-in keyboard is not disabled properly.

Do I miss something or there is another way to do the job??

Answer (score 0):

When I restarted my macbook, it worked... so it is a right way to solve this problem.
If you have another ideas, just comment it.